# UITextView does not show attributes' editing options for attributed text

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uitextview, xcode4.6, nsattributedstring

I've created an app that uses a `UITextView` Text View with the *Text* set to *Attributed* and with the option *Allow Attributes Editing* enabled.. from what I've understood, this should allow the user to edit some attributes, such as *Boldface*, *Italic* etc when he selects a portion of the text contained within the *TextView*.. I launched the app within the IOS 6.1 Simulator and if I select some text within the `UITextView` it does not show any attributes' editing option, is it a simulator issue or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[There's a known bug with Xcode 4.X where the "allows editing attributes" checkbox in Interface Builder is apparently not working](http://openradar.appspot.com/12658954).

To fix this, you need to programmatically set the "`allowsEditingTextAttributes`" property of your UITextView via an IBOutlet.

Comment: Isn't it quite "crazy" that such a bug is still around after more than 8 months? I know it's not critical, I was just wondering why they did not solve it in so many months :)

Comment: It's totally unbelievable - you're right.  Apple suck.

Comment: Just to help others. It is the year *2017* and this bug still exists.